# Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom causes web app crash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to load a DLL from internet, more specifically it is Azure storage (Blob), so I used "Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom" like this:

```
Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom(@"https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/test/calculator.dll");
```

But becuaset this specific call, my web app (published) returns:

> "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process."

The weird part is if I am using my local build, it is fine. there is no crash and the return result is correct.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and .net 5.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue or how to debug it.

Thanks

Comment: Is the "test" container (in which the "calculator.dll" blob resides") set to allow public access?  (I wouldn't recommend that, but the above line of code won't work without it.)  Better solution is probably to create a Shared Access Signature to access the blob, and pass the full URL (URl above + the SAS) into Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom() (or whatever else you use.)  Without one of these two solutions, the request to Azure Storage won't be authenticated.

Comment: @AdamSorrin-MSFT Yes, that dll is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple way, you could achieve your purpose by the following code:

**calculator.dll**

```
public class Calculator
{
    public string HelloWorld(string userName)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello world, {0}!", userName);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    string url = "https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/dll/calculator.dll";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    //load assembly from bytes
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
    var calc = assembly.CreateInstance("calculator.Calculator");
    //invoke the method and get result
    var result = calc.GetType().InvokeMember("HelloWorld", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, calc, new[] { "Bruce" });
    ViewData["result"] = result;
    return View();
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: It can work. The other working way is downloading the file first and then use it.